# SVG transform: scale to matrix value?

Tags: matrix, svg, sprite, transform, scale

I'm using svg to create Game Levels for my game. I parse the svg file to see where to position my sprites on the scene. I got x and y, but then I noticed that some elements have a "transform" attribute. 
I this attribute in my case contains a "matrix(A,B,C,D,E,F)" value that I parse into a structure and use this way.

The new sprite position is:

X = t.A * oldX + t.C * oldY + t.E;

Y = t.B * oldX + t.D * oldY + t.F;

The new sprite width and heigth are:

W = oldW * Math.Sqrt(t.A * t.A + t.B * t.B);

H = oldH * Math.Sqrt(t.C * t.C + t.D * t.D);

The rotation to apply to the sprite is:

R += ((180 / Math.PI) * Math.Atan2(t.D, t.C) - 90);

Usually it works but quite well always but in case of "matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0)" which is equivalent to the value "scale(1,-1)" which is a vertical flip.

The result in this case is the vertical flip I wanted but also a shift on the x acis of -oldW.

It seams that in the end scale(1,-1) is not the same of matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0)... 
Anybody could help to understand what's wrong in this case?

Note: I rotate my sprites always from the upper-left corner (and that's fine for every matrix I tried but the scale(1,-1)).

[EDIT]
Tnx for you comment. What I do is quite straight forward: 
I get the scale(1,-1) from the SVG element, and I convert it in a matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,0) like this:

```
public static Transform GetScale(float[] values)
{
    // here values is float[] { 1, -1 }
    return GetMatrix(new float[] { values[0], 0, 0, values[1], 0, 0 });
}

public static Transform GetMatrix(float[] values)
{
    // here values is float[] { 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 }
    var px = DeltaTransformPoint(values, new float[] { 0, 1 });
    var py = DeltaTransformPoint(values, new float[] { 1, 0 });

    var skewX = ((180 / Math.PI) * Math.Atan2(px[1], px[0]) - 90);
    var skewY = ((180 / Math.PI) * Math.Atan2(py[1], py[0]));

    return new Transform()
    {
        A = values[0],
        B = values[1],
        C = values[2],
        D = values[3],
        E = values[4],
        F = values[5],
        TranslateX = values[4],
        TranslateY = values[5],
        ScaleX = Math.Sqrt(values[0] * values[0] + values[1] * values[1]),
        ScaleY = Math.Sqrt(values[2] * values[2] + values[3] * values[3]),
        SkewX = skewX,
        SkewY = skewY,
        Rotation = skewX
    };
}

public static float[] DeltaTransformPoint(float[] values, float[] point)
{
    var dx = point[0] * values[0] + point[1] * values[2] + 0;
    var dy = point[0] * values[1] + point[1] * values[3] + 0;

    return new float[] { dx, dy };
}
```

Then the Transform object is the one going into the code I posted before which says:

```
var X = t.A * oldX + t.C * oldY + t.E
var Y = t.B * oldX + t.D * oldY + t.F
```

Es having a rectangle at (58,-67) with scale(1,-1) means:

```
var X = 1 + 58 + 0 + -67 + 0 = 58
var Y = 0 * 58 + -1 * -67 + 0 = 67
R = ((180 / Math.PI) * Math.Atan2(-1, 0) - 90) // this is -180
```

so my rectangle get shifted down, then the rotation of -180 is applyed. Rotating from the uppper-left corner of my rectangle the result is that the rectangle gets up-side down, but also shifted left of the width of the rectangle.

Comment: They are the same: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ScalingDefined create a [mcve] if you need more help

Comment: I edited the description. Don't pay attention to the px, py, screwX and screwY which are not even used in the example. The math is very simple and the result is what I really get. Basically applying the rotation of -180 is what brings me "too left" then I would...